# Python 2.5 to Python 2.2 converter

Tags: python, pys60

I am working on a PyS60 application for S60 2nd Edition devices. I have coded my application logic in Python 2.5.

Is there any tool that automates th conversion from Python 2.5 to Python 2.2 or do I need to do in manually?

Comment: "Python for S60 1.9.1 RELEASE NOTES, 24.01.2009"  "Python 2.5.1 core".  Why are you down-converting?  Please provide version numbers for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that would go from 2.5 to 2.2 automatically; but there was one a while ago that did 2.3 to 2.2 by [RADLogic](http://www.radlogic.com.au/downloads.htm).

Depending on how many recent features your code uses, it may be trivial to convert it manually.

I had to backport some code a while back and all it actually took was to define True and False if they weren't already defined, write up some simple replacements for `sum()`, `enumerate()`, etc, and grab old versions of modules like `datetime` and `logging` that weren't yet in the 2.2 standard library.

Answer (score 3):

The latest Python for S60, [1.9.0](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154215), actually includes Python 2.5.1. So maybe you don't need to convert.